# dart flutter - Why is this await unnecessary?

Tags: dart, async-await

my linter is telling me this `await` is unnecessary:
[image: await]

> Unnecessary await keyword in return.

I thought if you're calling a function inside an async function and you want to get/return the value, rather than the future you had to use `await` to designate you want the value, not the future.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's helpful to copy/paste your code rather than use a screenshot so people (like me) can copy/paste it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation for that recommendation points out](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_await_in_return.html), you can take off the `async` and just return the `Future`, rather than using `await`:

```
Future<Dictionary> get _localDir => getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

This is called "eliding async/await". Stephen Cleary wrote an article about it (written for C#, but largely applicable for any language that uses `async` and `await`), which you may find helpful: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

In short, it's more efficient to do this in situations when you can:

> By not including these keywords, the compiler can skip generating the async state machine. This means that there are fewer compiler-generated types in your assembly, less pressure on the garbage collector, and fewer CPU instructions to execute.

Comment: I think I see, because whatever calls `_localDir` will eventually await the future anyway, so I can just pass back the Future. Got it.